# Cordova Limits of File.System.Plugin - developed using Visual Studio hybrid device apps extention

Tags: cordova, ripple, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I'm new to Cordova. I did my first Little App and deployed it to Windows 8 and Android successfully. Now I started testing the file System Plugin.

I did a Little test app which creates a text file of a given size. Results:

- On Android the app stopps responding without an error message somewhere between 10 and 15 MB of Filesize
- On Windows 8 the app crashes without an error message while createing a file bigger than 40 KB (not MB!!! it is KB)
- On Ripple Emulator the file System Plugin is not really supported

(Edit: For Windows 8 there ist a Bug in the Cordova Code right now when saving Blobs. So if the Code is changed to just save the plain string I could manage to save a file up to 1 GB - This Change has no Effekt for Android so, still there is the 10 MB Limit :EditEnd)

I basically just copied the Code from the HTML5 Rocks docu and build a bigger sting to store...

So what are the Limits or do I do something wrong here? Any help would be great!

greetings, Markus

here is my code:

```
function writeFile() {
    window.requestFileSystem(window.PERSISTENT, 5 * 1024 * 1024 /*5MB*/, onInitFsWrite, errorHandler);
}

function onInitFsWrite(fs) {
    console.log('Opened file system: ' + fs.name);

    fs.root.getFile(_fileName, {}, function (fileEntry) {

        // Create a FileWriter object for our FileEntry (log.txt).
        fileEntry.createWriter(function (fileWriter) {

            fileWriter.onwriteend = function (e) {
                msgOut('Write completed.');
            };

            fileWriter.onerror = function (e) {
                msgOut('Write failed: ' + e.toString());
            };

            //create some data
           var text = "1234567890".repeat(parseInt($("#length").val()));

            // Create a new Blob and write it to log.txt.
            var blob = new Blob([text], { type: 'text/plain' });

            fileWriter.write(blob);

        }, errorHandler);

    }, errorHandler);
}

String.prototype.repeat = function (num) {
    return new Array(num + 1).join(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onInitFsWrite, errorHandler);`

Cordova's implementation of the requestFileSystem API uses the LocalFileSystem object instead of a window object

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but this is not changing anything. I'm not sure, but I think I found the reason for the limit. Android Apps have a max Memory usage and it looks like the RAM usage is the Problem and not the limit of writing files. In my sample code I build up a big string and on passing it to the native layer it is probably copied over, and the string is UNICODE, so we have two byte for every char, and so the Operation is reaching the RAM Limit of Android apps. In native code I have similar Problems, but if I use streaming techniqes, everything works fine...

Comment: @Markus I thought so too, but lately I managed to port part of rikaikun to phonegap on android. The dictionary takes whooping 70MB and I can actually load it, but: a) I have to use good old ajax request to do it b) this works only on files that were included in the app itself (I cannot access any external files using XHR).